# How to draw multiple line text to uiimageview iphone?

Tags: iphone, text, uiimageview, uitextview

I have UITextView for text, after user press DONE, I convert text to UIImageView and show it. It works with one line of text very good,

and [Screenshot 1](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/mn6v6)

. But if user types two lines, or more: the result is still one line??? [Screenshot 2](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/8ufuq)

I want to display two or more lines in UIimageView

Can anybody help me! Thank you very much!

Here is my code:

```
-(UIImage *)convertTextToImage : (ObjectText *) objT; 
{ 
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(([objT.content sizeWithFont:objT.font].width+10), ([objT.content sizeWithFont:objT.font].height+10)));
    [[objT getcolor] set];
    [objT.content drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(5, 5) withFont:objT.font];
    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();     
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); 
    return result; 
}
```

Comment: This is my code: -(UIImage *)convertTextToImage : (ObjectText *) objT;
{
    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(([objT.content sizeWithFont:objT.font].width+10), ([objT.content sizeWithFont:objT.font].height+10)));
    [[objT getcolor] set];
    [objT.content drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(5, 5)
                     withFont:objT.font];
    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return  result;
}

Comment: What is the width that you want to constrain the text to?

Comment: It is based on size and font of text: [string sizeWithFont:objT.font].width

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are relying on the `sizeWithFont` method to totally control the size of your label.  Without constraining the width, the label will always expand to a frame wide enough for the text to display on one line.

Try this (the code will constrain the width to a width you specify):

```
-(UIImage *)convertTextToImage : (ObjectText *) objT; 
{ 
    //THIS IS THE MAX WIDTH YOU WANT, and anything wider would wrap to two lines
    CGFloat desiredWidth = 100.0;
    CGSize sizeToConstrainTo = CGSizeMake(desiredWidth, 5000);
    CGSize newSize = [objT.content sizeWithFont:objT.font
                              constrainedToSize:sizeToConstrainTo
                                  lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [[objT getcolor] set];
    [objT.content drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(5, 5) withFont:objT.font];
    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();     
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); 
    return result; 
}
```

Comment: thanks obuseme but, objT.content.numberOfLines = 2;...error..because numberOfLines not found on object of type NSString...

Comment: oh you're right, sorry about that, just remove that line entirely, I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

**Abstracted Attributes**

```
NSString* textContent = @"Hello, World!";
NSString* text2Content = @"Hello, World!"; 
NSString* text3Content = @"Hello, World!"; 
NSString* text4Content = @"Hello, World!";
```

**Text Drawing - 1**

```
CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(65, 43, 56, 55);
[[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
[textContent drawInRect: textRect withFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica" size: 12] lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment: UITextAlignmentCenter];
```

**Text Drawing - 2**

```
CGRect text2Rect = CGRectMake(77, 79, 37, 31);
[[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
[text2Content drawInRect: text2Rect withFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica" size: 12] lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment: UITextAlignmentCenter];
```

**Text Drawing - 3**

```
CGRect text3Rect = CGRectMake(118, 74, 49, 43);
[[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
[text3Content drawInRect: text3Rect withFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica" size: 12] lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment: UITextAlignmentCenter];
```

**Text Drawing - 4**

```
CGRect text4Rect = CGRectMake(71, 17, 41, 28);
[[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
[text4Content drawInRect: text4Rect withFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica" size: 12] lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment: UITextAlignmentCenter];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer, I think it is the good way. Try this code:

-(UIImage *)convertTextToImage : (ObjectText *) objT;
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake([objT.content sizeWithFont:objT.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(900, 900)].width+10, [objT.content sizeWithFont:objT.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(900, 900)].height+10));

```
[[objT getcolor] set];

[objT.content drawInRect:CGRectMake(5, 5, [objT.content sizeWithFont:objT.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(900, 900)].width, [objT.content sizeWithFont:objT.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(900, 900)].height) withFont:objT.font];

UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return  result;
```

}